# ajax popup not showing when button clicked

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax, popup

I am using the code below to try to create a popup that displays text and a few buttons. The problem is that when the button is clicked the popup does not show up and the page reloads.

```
<script type="text/javascript"             src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#button1").live("click", function () {
        $("#popup").dialog({
            title: "Display",
            width: 600,
        })
        return false;
    });
</script>

<asp:Button ID="button1" ClientId="button1" runat="server" Text="testpopuo" />
<div>
<div id="popup" style="display:none">
    <asp:Literal Text="Are you sure you want to delete the blog?"  runat="server"/>
    <asp:Button Text="Yes" runat="server" />
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try to remove runat="server" from button1

Comment: You need to use the client id of the control as ASP.Net will change the id="button" to something else to suit its needs. Have you included jQuery as well as jQuery UI as it is not shown in the example? As the code precedes the elements in the page you also need to wrap it in a DOM ready event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to include jQuery js too (you only show the jQuery UI script). Put that before the jQueryUI include
2. You can set the ClientIDMode="Static" ASP.net property so that `ID` is left unchanged. There are a few options available: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx
3. You need to wrap your jQuery code in a DOM ready handler as it precedes the elements on the page. `$(function(){YOUR CODE HERE});` is a short-cut for `$(document).ready(function(){YOUR CODE HERE});`

Code:

```
<script src="your jQuery.js path here" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#button1").live("click", function () {
            $("#popup").dialog({
                title: "Display",
                width: 600,
            })
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:Button ID="button1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="testpopuo" />
<div>
<div id="popup" style="display:none">
    <asp:Literal Text="Are you sure you want to delete the blog?"  runat="server"/>
    <asp:Button Text="Yes" runat="server" />
</div>
</div>
```

Looks like this when clicked:

[image]

Comment: I have added the jQuery UI script changed the $(function() to  $(document).ready(function(). but the popup is still not shown

Comment: @user3043862: Always use the shorter `$(function(){});`. Can you post your entire HTML again so we can spot any other/new issues. Thanks.

Comment: @user3043862: Just building a sample ASP app to test for any other issues.

Comment: @user3043862: Sorted... I forgot what the ID options were (been years since I used old ASP.Net). Use `ClientIDMode="Static"` on the control. Have tested the above and it works now.

Comment: Thank you! I have been trying to figure this out for sometime now.

Answer (score 1):

You are using query selector before button loaded. So write your code under jquery ready function.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#button1").live("click", function () {
        $("#popup").dialog({
            title: "Display",
            width: 600,
        })
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: That is only one of the problems.